# Screenshot capture of dual monitor in Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, screenshot, multiple-monitors

In the context of a Qt application, I'm using the following code snippet for taking a screenshot of the full desktop:

```cpp
QDesktopWidget* dw = QApplication::desktop();
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::grabWindow(dw->winId(), 0, 0,
                                     dw->width(), dw->height());
pixmap.save(name, "JPG", screenshot_quality);
```

This approach works pretty well in Linux and Windows and with dual monitor, independently of screen's resolutions; that is, it works still if the two monitors are working with different resolutions.

However, with Qt 5, I get the following run-time warning:

```cpp
static QPixmap QPixmap::grabWindow(WId, int, int, int, int) is deprecated, use QScreen::grabWindow() instead. Defaulting to primary screen.
```

So I reviewed the Qt 5 doc and I wrote this:

```cpp
QScreen * screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
QPixmap pixmap = screen->grabWindow(0);
pixmap.save(name, "JPG", screenshot_quality);
```

But this approach does not capture the second screen.

So I searched a little more and, according to this thread, [Taking Screenshot of Full Desktop with Qt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213942/taking-screenshot-of-full-desktop-with-qt5), I designed the screenshot capture as follows:

```cpp
QScreen * screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
QRect g = screen->geometry();
QPixmap pixmap = screen->grabWindow(0, g.x(), g.y(), g.width(), g.height());
pixmap.save(name, "JPG", screenshot_quality);
```

Unfortunately, this does not work either.

What catches my attention is that the method with Qt 4 works well. Since I imagine there must be some way to make it in Qt 5.

How can be done with Qt 5?

Comment: I've edited out the answer as it does not belong in the question, but in an answer box. If you wish to share it, please add it as an answer, otherwise I will be adding it as a community wiki. See [How to treat an old question which had an answer edited into it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289344/how-to-treat-an-old-question-which-had-an-answer-edited-into-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naturally, `QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()` will give you a single screen.

You could:

- Use `QList<QScreen *> QGuiApplication::screens()` to get all screens associated with the application.
- Take screenshots for all of them.
- Create another blank image.
- Size it according to how you want to compose the screens.
- Manually compose them into a final image using `QPainter`.

```cpp
QPixmap grabScreens() {
  auto screens = QGuiApplication::screens();
  QList<QPixmap> scrs;
  int w = 0, h = 0, p = 0;
  foreach (auto scr, screens) {
    QPixmap pix = scr->grabWindow(0);
    w += pix.width();
    if (h < pix.height()) h = pix.height();
    scrs << pix;
  }
  QPixmap final(w, h);
  QPainter painter(&final);
  final.fill(Qt::black);
  foreach (auto scr, scrs) {
    painter.drawPixmap(QPoint(p, 0), scr);
    p += scr.width();
  }
  return final;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For old Qt versions:

You can use primary screen's (desktop) [virtual geometry](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#virtualGeometry-prop) and capture entire desktop without additional loops and calculations:

```
QRect desktopGeometry = qApp->primaryScreen()->virtualGeometry();
QPixmap desktopPixmap = qApp->primaryScreen()->grabWindow(qApp->desktop()->winId(), desktopGeometry.x(), desktopGeometry.y(), desktopGeometry.width(), desktopGeometry.height());
```

See also: [QDesktopWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html)

---

For new Qt versions:

[QApplication::desktop()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication-obsolete.html#desktop) and [QDesktopWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html) are marked as obsolete, so for new projects it's recommended to use approach with screen enumerating.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by [lrleon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1561081/lrleon):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36775027/17726418), I came up with this:

```
QPixmap grabScreens()
{
  QList<QScreen*> screens = QGuiApplication::screens();
  QList<QPixmap> scrs;
  int w = 0, h = 0, p = 0;

  foreach (auto scr, screens)
    {
      QRect g = scr->geometry();
      QPixmap pix = scr->grabWindow(0, g.x(), g.y(), g.width(), g.height());
      w += pix.width();
      h = max(h, pix.height());
      scrs.append(pix);
    }

  QPixmap final(w, h);
  QPainter painter(&final);
  final.fill(Qt::black);
  foreach (auto scr, scrs)
    {
      painter.drawPixmap(QPoint(p, 0), scr);
      p += scr.width();
    }

  return final;
}
```